# python flask sending raw http response with jpeg encoded image

Tags: python, http, flask

I'm trying to send raw response (which is a jpeg image from my laptop camera) in python using flask, this is the particular snippet:

```py
@app.route("/")
def stream():
    frm = imencode('.jpg',cap.read()[1])[1].tobytes()
    resp = Response()
    resp.set_data(value="HTTP/1.1 200 Ok\nContent-Type:image/jpeg\nContent-Length:"+str(len(frm))+"\n\n"+str(frm))
    return resp
```

My browser seem to display it as text nonetheless. If initialize

```py
Response(frm.tobytes(), headers={"Content-Type":"image/jpeg"})
```

then then browser decodes the image ok. I'm not very good with web stuff, but from what I've found so far response consists of first line specifying the http version, response status code and respective message. Then come the header fields each on new line. then a clean line separates metadata from the body. I've read that the bare minimum for a simple response are Content-Type and Content-Length headers. Some sources also mention using \r in combination with \n to separate the lines but i didn't find the example so far and this source didn't specify where exactly \r should be added.

Comment: Flask has `send_file()` method for this that accepts a `BinaryIO`  https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/?highlight=send_file#flask.send_file

Comment: `len(frm)` is probably not the same thing as `len(frm.tobytes())`, which is the actual content that the Content-Length header is supposed to be describing.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks for pointing this out, totally slipped my eye. changed it, will edit the question now.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, as far as i know send_file does send the file which browser automatically downloads, which is not the goal here. But I gave it a try, sadly this turned out to be even worse - it straight away hangs until killed.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, in fact i jumped the gun here - it doesnt crash (i just had bit too many tabs open at the end of the day), but doesnt work either. The error it gives is "TypeError: Unable to detect the MIME type because a file name is not available. Either set 'download_name', pass a path instead of a file, or set 'mimetype'." which to me sounds like it expects an actual file which browser tries to download.

Comment: You should be able to pass  `mimetype="image/jpeg"` parameter, but yes, resizing the image wouldn't hurt

Comment: @OneCricketeer, the entire purpose of that script is to determine a way to compose the request manually. I use python because i dont want to flash microcontroller if i can test it on my normal machine.

Comment: That is why i deliberately try to not use any wrappers from flask and instead compose the response by parts.

Comment: `Response` object from Flask is a "wrapper", though. If you wanted a raw HTTP server you should just use [`http.server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html). So, the fact that you have imported Flask and are using its classes means you also should use its utility methods. In any case, you don't need carriage returns in HTTP responses.